# Placing a JavaFX custom control in a GridPane

Tags: javafx, custom-controls, fxml

I followed Oracle's Mastering FXML tutorial, specifically the [tutorial for making a custom control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm#BABDAAHE), works fine as a standalone. But if I want to place this custom control in a GridPane, how can I place it with the GridPane's column and row attributes? Trying to place the custom control in the FXML file just gives me an error that the class is not a valid type.

My custom control FXML (view_navigation.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<Button>
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="@/toolbarButtonGraphics/navigation/Back24.gif"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
<Button text="Add Entry"  />
<Button text="Change Entry"  />
<Button text="View List"  />
<Button>
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="@/toolbarButtonGraphics/navigation/Forward24.gif"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
</fx:root>
```

Its associated class (ViewNavigationControl.java):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class ViewNavigationControl extends HBox {

public ViewNavigationControl() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view_navigation.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }

    }
}
```

Placing it at the bottom of the parent view's GridPane, per the very last paragraph in the tutorial:

```
....
    <HBox GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
        <ViewNavigationControl />
    </HBox>
</GridPane>
```

I get `javafx.fxml.LoadException: ViewNavigationControl is not a valid type.`

THANKS for any help at all!

Comment: What's the package of `ViewNavigationControl` and did you add a `<?import ?>` for it? (Note that using the default package could be problematic...)

Comment: Sheesh. I guess this is why I don't do this for a living! ;-) That's all it was. Thanks, I do appreciate you taking the time to take a look.